# Filtering Columns According to Two Value Thresholds

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, countif

If I can only have a maximum of 2 `Lateral` and a maximum of 3 `Zagueiro`, and they **cannot repeat values from Column 3**, how should I do it?

I've already tried using `QUERY` with multiple `"Limit"` and already tried using `FILTER(ISNA(MATCH()))` but in both options the desired answer is not found.

Note: There can be no preference between `Lateral` and `Zagueiro`, the sequence of values is what counts as a rule, the higher, the more important.

Note 2: It may happen to find less than 2 `Lateral` or less than 3 `Zagueiro`

Example Data:

```
Filipe Luís            Lateral          Flamengo
Willian Arão           Zagueiro         Flamengo
Aderlan                Lateral          Bragantino
Mariano                Lateral          Atlético-MG
Nathan Silva           Zagueiro         Atlético-MG
Tinga                  Lateral          Fortaleza
Marcelo Benevenuto     Zagueiro         Fortaleza
Fabrício Bruno         Zagueiro         Vasco
Joaquim                Lateral          Vasco
```

Example Expected Result:

```
Filipe Luís            Lateral          Flamengo
Aderlan                Lateral          Bragantino
Nathan Silva           Zagueiro         Atlético-MG
Marcelo Benevenuto     Zagueiro         Fortaleza
Fabrício Bruno         Zagueiro         Vasco
```

Note 3: It was a coincidence that the values in `Column 2` were perfectly separated, it can happen that the `Zagueiro` is above the `Lateral`, between two `Lateral` and so on. There is no specific sequence, everything goes according to the original sequence of data.

Note 4: `Column 2` will only have the two values mentioned, there will be no others.

**Link To Spreadsheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JmX7V2zAYh-O0POOc0BpRp9ejcgLFRtsGZwlruRgHdY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the sample data shown in your post, being sure to set the permissions initially (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Edit." This will be the most effective and efficient way to create, test and share a solution with you (and it will be a complex solution). Please also clarify whether the second column will ONLY contain "Lateral" or "Zagueiro," or whether other values besides these two may appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:C, B1:B="Lateral")), 2, 3);
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(A1:C, B1:B="Zagueiro", REGEXMATCH(C1:C, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(FILTER(C1:C, B1:B="Zagueiro"), 
 NOT(COUNTIFS(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(FILTER(C1:C, B1:B="Lateral")), 2, 3), 
 FILTER(C1:C, B1:B="Zagueiro"))))))), 3, 3)}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello friend, I did a test with other data but they ended up repeating the values of the third column, what is the best way to prevent this from happening? I left the new example in the spreadsheet for easier viewing, thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrondbyIF could be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZcRx.png but you should note that there are multiple solutions and formula can take only one route that may or may not be the route you expecting (especially when dataset is smaller)

Comment: I'll analyze and possibly use VLOOKUP separately, combining B&C to limit the values, then using your first formula indicated, I think it solves that way too without pushing the path to the formula so much. Thank you so much for everything!

Answer (score 1):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in E1:

`=ArrayFormula({VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B&C1:C,B1:B=B1)),2,1),{B1:B&C1:C,A1:C},{2,3,4},FALSE);VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B&C1:C,B1:B<>B1,ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1:C,QUERY(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B&C1:C,B1:B=B1)),2,1),{B1:B&C1:C,C1:C},2,FALSE),"Select *"),1,FALSE)))),3,1),{B1:B&C1:C,A1:C},{2,3,4},FALSE)})`